# Accept uni or multi-dimensional parameter in PL/SQL function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a function `nbrJobs()` in PL/SQL that counts the number of jobs that a user has had in the past.

In order to do this I first need to determine the "employee id", which can be determined by a pair (first name, last name).

I manage to do this when the arguments of the function are:

```
nbrJobs(firstName IN VARCHAR2(20), lastName IN VARCHAR2(25))
```

Then, this simple test runs without any problem:

```
DECLARE
  nbrJobsTotal NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT nbrJobs(first_name, last_name) INTO nbrJobsTotal 
  FROM employees
  WHERE employee_id = 101
END
```

Now, the problem is that my function should also work with that kind of call:

```
SELECT nbrJobs(first_name, last_name) INTO nbrJobsTotal FROM employees
```

with table `employees` containing multiple tuples.

So, now I'm confused about the input parameters type.. Should I use a `VARRAY`, a nested `TABLE`, a `CURSOR`, something else ?
What does a `SELECT` actually returns if multiple rows are selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PL/SQL function is executed for each row of the `SELECT` statement. Therefore, if you call your function in a regular `SELECT` SQL statement you will get a value for each record.

Here is an example by concatenating the first and last name together:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NAME (p_FIRST_NAME IN VARCHAR2, p_LAST_NAME IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN p_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || p_LAST_NAME;
END;
/

SELECT first_name, last_name, name(first_name, last_name) FROM HR.employees;

FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   NAME(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME)
----------  ---------   --------------------------
Ellen       Abel        Ellen Abel
Sundar      Ande        Sundar Ande
Mozhe       Atkinson    Mozhe Atkinson
David       Austin      David Austin
```

As you can see, for each row the PL/SQL function is executed and concatenates the first and last name and then is returning the result as a new column to the `SELECT` statement. There is no need for you to change the function to make it work with multiple row.

Now how would you be executing this inside PL/SQL with the SELECT statement that you have used as example above. You will either have to loop over the results with a cursor or you could use a collection type if you just want to fetch the result of all of the rows into a variable.

Using a cursor (
I'm demonstrating this on my example above by using the [Cursor FOR LOOP](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.htm#LNPLS1143)):

```
BEGIN
   FOR result IN (SELECT first_name, last_name, name(first_name, last_name) name FROM HR.employees) LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(result.first_name || ', ' || result.last_name || ', ' || result.name);
    END LOOP;
END;
/

Ellen, Abel, Ellen Abel
Sundar, Ande, Sundar Ande
Mozhe, Atkinson, Mozhe Atkinson
David, Austin, David Austin
```

What happens here is that I'm executing the very same `SELECT` statement but now inside the Cursor FOR LOOP which allows me to loop over each individual row that has been return. In this case I just print the result out into the console.

If you want to just save all the rows into a variable you will have to use a [PL/SQL Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/plsql-collections-and-records.htm#LNPLS005):

```
DECLARE
  -- Specify cursor with expected results
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT first_name, last_name, name(first_name, last_name) name
    FROM HR.employees;

  -- Create PL/SQL type for a nested table of the rowtype of the cursor (first_name, last_name, name)
  TYPE NameSet IS TABLE OF c1%ROWTYPE;

  employees  NameSet;  -- Instantiate a variable of the nested table of records

BEGIN 
  -- Assign values to nested table of records:

  SELECT first_name, last_name, name(first_name, last_name) name
    BULK COLLECT INTO employees
    FROM HR.employees;

  -- Print nested table of records:

    FOR i IN employees.FIRST .. employees.LAST LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
        employees(i).first_name || ' ' ||
        employees(i).last_name  || ', ' ||
        employees(i).name
      );
    END LOOP;
END;
/

Ellen Abel, Ellen Abel
Sundar Ande, Sundar Ande
Mozhe Atkinson, Mozhe Atkinson
David Austin, David Austin
```

As you can see here the same `SELECT` is executed but here we use `BULK COLLECT INTO` rather than just `INTO`. This is because the `SELECT` is returning more than one row, hence we need to tell the compiler that we do indeed expect that so that the compiler doesn't throw an error that more rows have been returned.

Last but not least, given that you use the variable name `nbrJobsTotal` in your example `SELECT nbrJobs(first_name, last_name) INTO nbrJobsTotal FROM employees` above, I think what you really want to try to do here is to sum up all the number of different jobs that employees had in your company. You can accomplish just that but using the built-in `SUM()` function which is an aggregation function, i.e it will only return one row without a `GOUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(nbrJobs(first_name, last_name)) INTO nbrJobsTotal FROM employees
```

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer. After all it was simple !

Comment: @Xing What are you even talking about. I'm not being sarcastic. "After all it was simple" means that I tried many complicated things and totally lost myself whilst in fact I just had to keep it simple, and gvenzl helped me understand that with his complete answer, hence the "Thank you".

Comment: No hard feelings! I was pretty sure that the answer was just a `SUM()` over the function but I thought that rather than giving a one line answer I add a bit more context on how PL/SQL functions work. Right in the spirit of "Give a man a fish and he can eat for a day, teach him how to fish and he can eat for a lifetime". Hopefully this explanation has not only helped @ArthurDeschamps but will also help many others in future finding this question. As to the rest, I'm happy that the problem is solved and (hopefully) something has been learned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Table of` `Type` - to `bulk collect` all rows returned by the `select` statement.

Based on your example it would look like this:

```
DECLARE
  nbrJobsTotal NUMBER;
  TYPE jobsTotalTable_type IS TABLE OF nbrJobsTotal%TYPE; 
  jobsTotalTable jobsTotalTable_type ;
BEGIN
  --bulk collect results  
  SELECT nbrJobs(first_name, last_name) BULK COLLECT INTO  jobsTotalTable 
  FROM employees;

  --print results  
  FOR indx IN 1 .. jobsTotalTable.COUNT LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(jobsTotalTable (indx));
  END LOOP;
END
```